# Dropdown menu on custom page with product to choose number of products per page

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, pagination

I have almost zero knowledge with Wordpress and Wocoommerce cores and api's so, please bear with me.

I have showing ~140 products on custom page (e.g. not the default shop page for woocommerce) trough `WooCommerce Product Filter`.

The products are on page and everything is fine except there is no way to show dropdown `Products per page` which I can choose how many products to show on page.

So, I've found some tutorials and currently I have this in my `function.php`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'ps_selectbox', 25 );
function ps_selectbox() {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);     
    echo '<span>Per Page: </span>';
    echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';   
    $orderby_options = array( '8' => '8', '16' => '16','32' => '32','64' => '64' );
    foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
        echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ps_pre_get_products_query' );
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_page() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
    }
}

function render_ps_sel() {
    return ps_selectbox();
}
add_shortcode( 'ps_selectbox', 'render_ps_sel' );
```

I'm render the dropdown menu trough the shortcode above `[ps_selectbox]` but whatever I choose the number of the products on the page is always same and nothing change.

Comment: First thing I noticed is that there appears to be a typo on row 3 for `$per_page` as the second parameter for `filter_input`is `perpagee` and on row 14 it's just `perpage`.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen it's fixed. Just copied wrong snipped. Edited in question too.

Comment: I updated the code example in my answer, if you want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work?

```
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_woocommerce() && is_page() ) {
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
    }
}
```

<s>I tested your code and the if statement didn't seem to work with `is_page()` (*but that could also be because my local WP sandbox is a mess*). To my knowing `posts_per_page` expects `int` and `var_dump` showed that `$per_page` was a string.</s>

**EDIT** My local WP sandbox is a mess, so that's why `is_page` wasn't working. I tested the code again on another install.

**EDIT 2** Let's see how many times I can get this wrong. I updated the code to something that works (*at least on another local WP sandbox*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tested it but sadly it didn't work on my end. I don't know why. The products are set to 10 by default on the `WooCommerce Product Filter`. I've select 64 from the dropdown. The page refreshed and the products are still 10.